# is it possible to return both Values on a hashtable in a single variable?

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have the following Hashtable in powershell:

```
$hash = @{"server" = "ou"; "server1" = "ou1"}
```

I use this to authenticate users against two ad servers and it works fine. I use a "foreach" loop to verify each user against both servers. I can return the right value if the user exists in just one server, but I do not know how to make it return both values if the user exits in both servers. Can anyone help?

```
foreach($user in $csv.GetEnumerator())
{
  foreach($server in $hash.Keys)
}
```

Comment: `I can return the right value if the user exists in just one server` - paste that code. What is the relation between user and `$hash`. What is in `$scv`?

Comment: I believe you may be referring to    $csv? that is what I use to import a CSV with that contains the users.